# Check if 1 or more files with the same name, but with different extensions, exist in a same folder in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wrote this code to check if there are files with the same name "planning" in the "upload" folder, but with only  pdf or html extension. I know, this syntax is not optimized but it works. I think there are shorter and simpler ways.

Does anyone have any examples to share with me?

Thanks.

```
<script>
    function FileExists(url)
    {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('HEAD', url, false);
        http.send();
        return http.status!=404;
    }
    
    var source = "upload/planning_11";
    var pdf_file = FileExist(source+".pdf");            
    var html_file = FileExist(source+".html");  
            
    if (pdf_file==true && html_file==false) {
    $('#exist_file_pdf').show();
    $('#exist_file_html').hide();
    $('#exist_file_all').hide();
    } else if (pdf_file==false && html_file==true) {
    $('#exist_file_html').hide();
    $('#exist_file_html').show();
    $('#exist_file_all').hide();
    } else if (pdf_file==true && html_file==true) {
    $('#exist_file_html').hide();
    $('#exist_file_html').hide();
    $('#exist_file_all').show();
    } else if (pdf_file==false && html_file==false) {
    $('#exist_file_html').hide();
    $('#exist_file_html').hide();
    $('#exist_file_all').hide();
    }
</script>
    
    <div id="exist_file_pdf">PDF planning file exist</div>
    <div id="exist_file_html">HTML planning files exist</div>
    <div id="exist_file_all">PDF and HTML planning files exists !</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use async false

Instead you can do this

```js
const source = "upload/planning_11";
const pdfUrl = source + ".pdf";
const htmlUrl = source + ".html";
$('#exist_file_all').hide();
$('#exist_file_html').hide();
$('#exist_file_pdf').hide();

$.ajax({
  type: 'HEAD',
  url: pdfUrl
  success: function(msg) {
    $('#exist_file_pdf').show();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'HEAD',
      url: htmlUrl
      success: function(msg) {
        $('#exist_file_html').show();
        if ($('#exist_file_html').is(":visible") && 
            $('#exist_file_pdf').is(":visible")) {
          $('#exist_file_all').show();
          $('#exist_file_html').hide();
          $('#exist_file_pdf').hide();
        } 
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you !!!
Your code is perfect but how to hide  'exist_file_pdf' and 'exist_file_html', if  'exist_file_all' is displayed?

Comment: It was so simple. Every time a solution is found after long hours of searching, I have the same feeling when Santa Claus was passing. Thank you very much.